# Pressing backspace with root gives weired character in putty

Tags: putty

I am using putty to make ssh connection with my server.

I use up and down arrow button to go through history commands.

but now when i press backspace instead of deleting the character , some weired chacater appear like

```
service mysql stop


 service mysql stop^?^?^?
```

why is that , everything was ok before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the key while logged in by entering `stty erase <then hit the backspace>`  That will set the backspace to whatever character you are sending as backspace for that terminal session. tylerl's response is a better long-term fix.

Answer (score 4):

In the putty options under `Terminal` >> `Keyboard` there's an option to change your backspace emulation. Change it and see if it makes things better.

Alternately (or additionally) mess around with the checkboxes under `Terminal` >> `Features` to see if one of those (such as "Disable destructive backspace...") fixes your problem.

There's a complex interaction between terminals and hosts using a set of conflicting standards which makes getting the right match a bit of a trial-and-error exercise.

Answer (score 4):

And just something to have in mind. Generally, if backspace doesn't work, try with `ctrl + H`

Answer (score 1):

If the backspace was working okay initially and no longer is then try using the "reset" command. Look around putty's options menu for a "send hard reset" option as well. If it was never working then try what tylerl suggested.